# android detect amperage from charger

Tags: android

I am trying to detect (if it is possible) the amperage coming from the charger/usb.
is getting the intent extra - EXTRA_VOLTAGE will help me achieve that?
sometimes the USB produces different amperage - 1000mA and sometimes less. How can I know the amperage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is a sticky broadcast

```
this.registerReceiver(this.batReceiver,     
    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

private BroadcastReceiver batReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
    int voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, 0);

    int source = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);     

    }    
  };
```

It seems you want the charger source use EXTRA_PLUGGED 0 for battery, 1 for AC and 2 for USB

Comment: I know. but will EXTRA_VOLTAGE get what I want?? the CHARGER voltage and not the BATTERY voltage?

Comment: Are you sure?? isn't USB produces 5V while AC produces 12V?

Comment: Not quite... this distinguish I know. but my question is - if the USB has a few currents available - like 5V or 8V, can I know that??

Comment: There is no such support in the android API. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

u have to use receiver and initilize like this in android manifestfile

```
 <receiver android:name=".reboot" android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" android:label="StartServiceAtBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTRA_VOLTAGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in reciver file

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if("android.intent.action.EXTRA_VOLTAGE".equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
}
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong. don't use the EXTRA in an intent filter as an ACTION. You need to use the BATTERY_CHANGED action, and take the EXTRA_VOLTAGE FROM that. Then, you need to understand that the EXTRA_VOLTAGE contains the *battery* voltage and not the charger.